# to count the number of times do state of bulb changed?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, boolean

Today in the coding challenge I faced a problem which is Toggled Switches(Hacker Earth) as it is a coding challenge question So, I am unable to send the question or its link (exactly).

- Problem: we have to print a number representing the number of times
  do bulb changed its state.  The bulb is attached to the "n" number of
  switches. So the bulb will be in the "on" state only when half or
  more than half of the given n of switches to be "on".
- 1 represents on state
- 0 for off respectively.
- There is also a query that will be given to represent which switch
  has to be toggled ( change from on to off or vice-versa 1 ->0 or
  0->1). So, by toggling may or may not the bulb state change. so we have to return the number of times it changed its
  state.

*input:*

- 1 - number of test case
- 3 - number of switches (n)
- 1 1 0 - initial all n    switches states
- 3 - number of switches to be toggled
- 3 2 1 -> (3    represents third switch i.e as index wise second in
  switches array.)    switches that have to be toggled.

*output:*

- 1  - number of times the bulb changed its state

.

- **explanation**
- initial array or switches state  [1, 1, 0] as half or more than half
  switches are in on. hence bulb is in on state.

as per queries [3,2,1]

- we have to toggle the 3 rd switch. As initially third is in off [1,1,0] after toggling it changes to on [1,1,1] present switches state. as all are in on position bulb is on. ( no changes in the state of the bulb)
- Now, have to toggle 2 nd switch so [1,1,1] changes to [1,0,1] switches states as half switches are on the bulb is on. ( no changes in the state of the bulb)
- Now, 1 st switch to be toggled. Hence [1,0,1] changes to [0,0,1]. as not equal or more than half switches are in on states hence bulb is going to be off. ( now bulb state is changed)
- Hence the output is one.
- I wrote the answer to this I am only able to solve the sample test case. No hidden test case is got the right answer and some got time exceeds error. so totally 0 marks.
- I am a beginner so please explain vividly where I am wrong what is wrong? how it can be efficient ?.
- and my code is

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int test_cases = scan.nextInt();
    while(test_cases>0){
        //number of switches
        int n  = scan.nextInt();
        // contains on / off positions of switches
        int [] switches = new int[n];
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
        switches[i]=scan.nextInt();
        //number of queries 
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        //  starts at 1 i.e queries[0]=1 but represents switch index 1(queries representing switch position and tha position starts from 1)
        int [] queries  = new int[q];
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
        queries[i]=scan.nextInt();
        int result  = toggled(n,switches,q,queries);
        System.out.println(result);
        test_cases--;
    }
    }
    static int toggled(int n,int switches[],int q,int queries[]){
        if(n==1)
        return q;
        int result =0;
        //giving switch state on or off
        boolean initial = on(switches);
        //System.out.println("initial is "+initial);
        //to represent on or off for all toggle including initial
        boolean [] states = new boolean[q+1];
        states[0] = initial;
        int count  = 0;
        //to represent index of states
        int state_count =1;
        while(count<q){
            if((switches[queries[count]-1] & 1 )== 1)
            switches[queries[count]-1] = 0;
            else
            switches[queries[count]-1] = 1;
     
     states[state_count++]=on(switches);
     count++;
        }
       //System.out.println("state_count is "+state_count);
       for(int i =1;i<state_count;i++){
           if(initial ^ states[i] )
           {
               result+=1;
               initial = states[i];
           }
       }
       return result;
    }
    //method to evaluate whether to consider on or off ( to on(bulb) have to on atleast half of the switches)
    static boolean on(int arr[]){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<arr.length;i++)
            sum+=arr[i];
        
        if(sum>arr.length/2.0)
            return true;
            else 
            return false;
            
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with HackerEarth. As I know it from other coding challenges platforms, they usually call given methods (for which they give you the signature) that will be called when the platform runs its tests to verify your solution. Read the instructions on the platform again, they might provide you with such information. If their test calls the `main` method using arguments, you might have to parse them into fields as well.

Comment: Yep, I am agree with you but the thing is I got the correct output for sample cases but other are hidden. So, to pass them there may be some wrong in my code. I am waiting for that and some outputs of mine are time exceeds error. hence there is a space of efficiency. So Can you please suggest solution changes for efficiency and hidden test cases gets passed? sir.